# Simple 2 column CSS layout with nested divs

Tags: css, layout, positioning, html

I have good familiarity with CSS but for some reason I am unable to achieve the result I want in this case.

Here is the link to my test site

http://danberinger.com/test.html

Keep in mind that I want a 2 column layout and that the background wrapper color (gray) is not showing.  Instead the body background color image is being put in place of where the wrapper background should be.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dan, I think you should explain which browsers it works in and which ones it doesn't!  Good luck in your endeavors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div#wrapper    { overflow:hidden;  }
```

Also, depending on how you want the 3 divs laid out, you would need some combination of:

```
float:left
float:right
```

and/or

```
clear:left
clear:right
clear:both
```

Depending on your desired layout...